How can I "associate" vars to terms in Prolog
In Prolog, when I enter at the toplevel something like this:
X = [a-A, b-B, a-A].

I've associated some logical variables to terms using the - functor-- but importantly, the first and last pair in the list both have the same logical variable.
Let's say I have a list like this:
[a, b, a]

Is there any way to go from that to a list like the above? That is, pair up each term with a logical variable, the same term having the same var.

Can use:
keys_keyvals(Ks, KVs) :-
    keys_keyvals_(Ks, [], KVs).

keys_keyvals_([], _, []).
keys_keyvals_([K|L], S, [K-V|R]) :-
    keys_keyvals_seen(S, K, V, S, S1),
    keys_keyvals_(L, S1, R).

% End of list - add Key-Value pair to Seen list
keys_keyvals_seen([], K, V, S, [K-V|S]).
% Found match
keys_keyvals_seen([H-X|_], K, V, S, S) :-
    (   H == K
    % Definite match, no need to keep looking
    ->  !
    ;   H = K
    ),
    % Unifying after cut
    X = V.
% Keep looking
keys_keyvals_seen([H-_|T], K, V, S, S1) :-
    dif(H, K),
    keys_keyvals_seen(T, K, V, S, S1).

Result in swi-prolog:
?- keys_keyvals([a,b,a,b,c,b,c,d], KVs).
KVs = [a-_A, b-_B, a-_A, b-_B, c-_C, b-_B, c-_C, d-_].

This also handles the keys being var, e.g.:
?- keys_keyvals([a,b,b,c,X,X], KVs).
X = c,
KVs = [a-_, b-_A, b-_A, c-_B, c-_B, c-_B] ;
X = b,
KVs = [a-_, b-_A, b-_A, c-_, b-_A, b-_A] ;
X = a,
KVs = [a-_A, b-_B, b-_B, c-_, a-_A, a-_A] ;
KVs = [a-_, b-_A, b-_A, c-_, X-_B, X-_B],
dif(X, c),
dif(X, a),
dif(X, b).

... and it works in both directions, e.g.:
?- keys_keyvals(Ks, [a-A, b-B, a-X]).
Ks = [a, b, a],
A = X.


In other languages I'd say make a dictionary (hashtable) of mappings {a:A, b:B} and keep the starting list. Why store multiple copies of the pairs when you can look them up as needed? This code makes a list of unique pairs:
?- Items = [a,b,a],
   sort(Items, Keys),    % NB. removes duplicates
   pairs_keys_values(UniquePairs, Keys, _).

A helper predicate and maplist can turn it into the full redundant list of pairs, adding:
lookup(Pairs, Key, Key-Value) :-
    memberchk(Key-Value, Pairs). 

% and
maplist(lookup(UniquePairs), Items, AllPairs).


A different way using a SWI Prolog dict to track the keys-values, and a grammar to consume items and output pairs, is:
% K: key, V: value, Seen: dict of earlier pairs.
kv(Seen, [K-V|KVs]) --> [K],
                        {V = Seen.get(K, _)},
                        kv(Seen.put([K-V]), KVs).

kv(_, []) --> [].

items_pairs(Items, Pairs) :-
    once(phrase(kv(_{}, Pairs), Items)).

e.g.:
?- items_pairs([a,b,a], Pairs), Pairs = [a-test|_].

Pairs = [a-test, b-_, a-test]


The sort operation compromises generality - might not be correct if any keys are var.

I discovered something useful while perusing the SWI docs: library(varnumbers), which maps terms of the form '$VAR'(0) consistently to fresh variables. This essentially fulfills the problem I was trying to solve.

You have provided zero evidence.
